# Zooming a retrieved image from the remote server if tapped - Android

Tags: android, remote-server, zooming

Hi I am new to android and im trying to zoom an image if tapped.. the problem is the image that i want to be zoomed is from a database...
Here is my xml code..

```
`<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/labresultimage"
android:layout_width="460dp"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:src="@drawable/laboratory" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

And this is my java code..

```
`package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LaboratoryResultInformation extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.laboratoryresultinformation);

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


//display image using passed url
final String MY_URL_STRING = extras.getString("IMAGEURL_EXTRA");

new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labresultimage))
.execute(MY_URL_STRING);
}
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
this.bmImage = bmImage;

}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
String urldisplay = urls[0];
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
try {
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
}`
```

I googled but the only code i found works if the image itself is already located/saved at the drawables..

Answer (score 0):

once Image Bitmap is downloaded 
You can try, https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/tree/master/src/com/example/touch or https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview
keep Image view

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

It dose not matter whether you get the Bitmap Object form server or Locale.